# LCK_M_SCH_S, schema stability lock causing infinite waiting to execute proc

Tags: sql-server, locking, schema, stability

**LCK_M_SCH_S**, the schema stability lock  caused my stored proc to waiting forever. Is there any way to avoid or got over it?

Comment: procedure definition ?????

Comment: It's a proc with dynamic query, which uses sys.objects,sys.collumns and sys.types to get object information from any database on the sql server.

Comment: Can you post the query or part of the query?

Comment: What is the lock type and resource of the blocker?

Answer (score 2):

LCK_M_SCH_S is a schema stability lock. This lock is used when queries are being compiled and executed. Lengthy blocking by this type of lock suggest you have a long running query in one or more of your databases. Other than batches these long running queries there is no easy way to get around this type of lock.

Comment: No, just accessing master db to get  object information from any database on the sql server.

Comment: @jacodegroot, LCK_M_SCH_S is a schema stability lock.  A schema modification lock is LCK_M_SCH_M.

Comment: After Dan Guzman's comment I have changed my answer to reflect this is a schema stability lock and not a schema modifcation lock

Answer (score 1):

Sorry , My Question was not Clear, But I've got the Solution, inspired by  **Jaco de Groot's Answer** 
This lock was due to another Stored proc of masterdb.
 **sp_helpconstraint** ,used to find constraints on tables in current database. 
I used this in my Proc, to get Constraints Details on tables/views I was applying this on **View**, which caused LCK_M_SCH_S, as I found. 
Before applying this Proc, I tested for the object(whether type is 'U' or not), It works fine.

Comment: You should accept this answer to your question to show it close.